# Does/should my sandbox server need to be exactly like my production server?

Tags: amazon-beanstalk

I am a little new to cloud hosting. For the smallish projects I have done so far, I am used to having one sandbox/testing server and one production server, and that's it. Now I'm developing something that will likely come under a lot more strain, and I'd like to give Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk a try.

I have so far been developing a PHP application on an Ubuntu machine. Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk's AMIs, however, are all "Amazon Linux." Can I continue to develop on my Ubuntu machine, or should I switch to Amazon Linux for my testing environment as well?

Comment: You want your test environment to mirror as closely as possible the production environment, so there aren't surprises when your code runs on a different infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking two different questions.

### Does my dev server need to be exactly like my production server?

**No.**
You can do your development on whatever you want, and then deploy that code to whatever production environment you'd like.

---

### *Should* my dev server be exactly like my production server?

**Yes.** - It makes life much easer.

If your development and production environments are different you will eventually have the "It works on *my machine*" developer moment, where some developer (maybe even you) writes (and hopefully extensively tests) some code on the development machine, then deploys it into production and it breaks horribly (missing/mismatched library versions, a different interpreter, package differences between the two systems, binaries not where the app expects them to be, etc.).

This means you'll spend hours (maybe days) re-writing parts of your code to deal with the fact that production isn't like the machine you developed on.  Then one day you'll be in a release crunch and hacks start slipping in - `if (is_production) { A } else { B }` - and someone later will see that and think it's acceptable.

Your code quickly spirals into an unmaintainable mess, and your only option is [Seppuku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seppuku).

---

Bottom line?

Spare yourself the pain, suffering, and ritual disemboweling and try to develop and test on the same platform you're eventually going to deploy to.